# What does it means by "should have throwed me over for Abby" ?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context: Mary & Abby are college mates met each other after long time, Actually Abby is pregnant with a baby. Jason is husband for Abby. Jason is also from same college.

> Mary: You was in the same shape last time I saw you.
>
> Abby: I know.
>
> Mary: Jason, don't you know what keeps causing this?
>
> Abby: Jason's after that boy he's wanted all these years.
>
> Mary: If you wanted a boy, **you never should have throwed me over for
>   Abby**.

Comment: Note that Mary is a non-standard/dialectal speaker (as evidenced by the first subject verb mismatch ***You was** [blah blah]*). The highlighted idiomatic usage [to throw someone over](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/throw-something-over.2813265/) means ***to abandon or reject someone, for example as a lover***. It's just a metaphoric extension from *throw [him] **overboard*** (off a ship, etc.).

Comment: ...in case you didn't realise, it should be ***thrown*** (not ***throwed***) in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario, it sounds like the three of them: Mary, Abby, and Jason are together talking.

Mary is remarking how Abby is pregnant each time they meet, and Abby explains that her husband keeps trying for to have a son.

Mary then says

> **you never should have throwed me over for Abby**.
>   *you never should have left me for Abby*

Obviously, Jason has been involved with both girls at some point.